# Change position of absolute divs on height change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to fix this behaivour in a template:

Template prints all the posts in a sequence of article tags with position absolute and setting his top in the perfect top position to avoid overlaps.

```
<div main>
    <article1 style="position absolute; top: 0px;"></article1> <!-- Have 210px of hegiht --!>
    <article2 style="position absolute; top: 211px;"></article2>
    ...
</div main>
```

Well, all shows well, but now they have implemented a faqs list plugin and these faqs use slide to show the content, when the faqs divs grows due the hegight change on show the content, next article top don't move, making overlapping.

I need to change this from the less intrusive way in the code. I was created a code to move the next element a fixed pixel from the bottom position of the faq article, but this is a problem when the faqs aren't the penultimate element. I leave here a little example that I created with the structure.

Any ideas to solve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/05onf82y/

Old code that I was using to solve this:

```
 jQuery(".ewd-ufaq-post-margin").click(function(){ //FAQ TITLE

            setTimeout(function(){
                FAQheight = 0;
                jQuery(".ewd-ufaq-post-active").each(function(){//FAQ CONTENT DIV
                    var _this = jQuery(this);
                    FAQheight += _this.height();
                });

                var faqsElement = jQuery(".ufaq-faq-list");
                var faqsParent = faqsElement.parents('article'); //FAQS ARTICLE PARENT
                var nextElement = faqsParent.next();
                var offset = faqsParent.offset();
                var top = offset.top;
                var bottom = top + faqsParent.outerHeight();

                faqsParent.nextAll("article[id^=post]").each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).css("top", bottom + 35);
                    //jQuery(this).css("top", nextElement.position().top + FAQheight);
                });



            }, 10);
        });
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `absolute` position. It will be quite easier to stack these articles if you remove it and the article will take up as much height as needed

Comment: The original functionallity of the website, We need not change within the possibilities